# Red5, h264 and HTML5 for devices (mobile include) most popular

Tags: html, mobile, h.264, red5

Currently I have a linux server (debian) with red5 providing streaming videos. It only uses flash/flv. Because of this it doesn't run on most mobile devices. I thought about using HTML5 and h.264 movies.

What do I need to do so that Red5 can provide streaming video using HTML5 for mobile devices?

Comment: Please have someone clean up the English. It's hard to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

red5 doesn't have to do anything to "stream" html5. Just put something like:

```
<video id="sampleMovie" src="HTML5Sample.mp4" controls></video>
```

in your html page and be sure the mp4 file is on your server. Several players do also support html5 (JWPlayer, Flowplayer, etc). And red5 can have a sleep ;-)